# Single sign on for multisite application across domains in rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, single-sign-on

There's a rails recipe that illustrates how to do this in rails 2, but now that sexy rack is in, the solution seemed no longer relevant. How can this be handled in rails 2.3.2?

Comment: Do you have a link to the recipe/solution? It would be easier with an example or some code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenID](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/openidauthentication)?